# I can't connect my phone as a debugging device

Tags: windows, usb-debugging, lg-g2

I have a newer phone (an LG G2), and I'm trying to develop on it using a new laptop for the first time (I've done this before w/ other phones and other computers).

I've installed all of the Android SDK and Java SDK components on the laptop.  On my phone, I've enabled Developer Options, and I've checked the "USB debugging" checkbox.

However, when I connect my phone to the laptop, I only get the standard dialog box for charging vs. viewing-files, etc.  I don't get prompted to accept an RSA Key... nothing happens.

I've run "adb devices", and the "List of devices attached" is empty.  I think I really need to purge my laptop of whatever driver it's using for this phone.  Charging and transferring-files works fine, but not debugging.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I've also checked Device Manager, and I don't see an "Android" section in my devices.  My phone is only listed under "Portable Devices" as "VS980 4G".

Also, When I connect my phone to my computer, I don't see the debugger icon in the notification tray of my phone.

Comment: Did you disable MTP?

Comment: How would a disable MTP, @HasH_BrowN? Thanks in advance

Comment: Settings>General>System>PC connection. When I use adb and it doesn't see my device I switch the MTP setting and my PC then sees the device.

Comment: Switch the MTP setting to what?  I only have these options: "Charge phone", "Media sync (MTP)", "Internet connection", and "Camera (PTP)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately got my phone to enter debugging mode by switching the USB setting to "Internet Connection".  Once I did that, I found MORE issues w/ my new Eclipse install, so I just switched to Android Studio and moved on w/ my life.